# Incremental sync from source to target table in snowflake

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm facing a data synchronization challenge where I need to keep the target table updated based on changes in the source table. The source table contains processed data, and it gets truncated and loaded with new data regularly. My goal is to efficiently update the target table incrementally, meaning I only want to affect the parts of the target table that have changed, performing insertions, deletions, and updates accordingly.

I attempted to use streaming with a merge operation, but I encountered problems when the source table is truncated before the new data is loaded.

Could you please suggest the optimal approach for handling this scenario?

Comment: If your source data is being truncated before you’ve processed it then you need to ensure this doesn’t happen. I’m not sure what help/suggestions you are expecting here - no suggestion about how to process the data is going to survive the loss of that data

Comment: I thought streams will work me but that is not the case and I think it works well for temporal tables type